# Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)". <=============> 100% CONFIGURING [36s] > IDLE

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools, gradle-daemon

info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in D:\AndroidEmulater\SDK\licenses
License for package Android SDK Tools accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [2m 17s]

I am having this problem even i am using latest version of android studio

I have tried to download different android apis but problem still there

Answer (score 4):

My problem got solved. If you are installing packages first time then problem comes maybe because of slow internet connection or slow computer. I just left it **IDLE** but some time package was installed. So I think you just need to be patient.